# year function in standardsql mode in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am writing a query to compare year filed with current year and I am using this command in BigQuery `string((year(current_date())))` .
I am getting error that `" ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. ."` for the line `(d.month) = String(Month((order.order_timestamp)))` since its not comparing the columns in table rather just using the month from timestamp. Is there a work around?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  INTEGER(SUM(order2.demand_amount_usd)),
  order2.quarter_name,
  order2.year
FROM (
  SELECT
    order1.demand_amount_usd,
    order1.order_timestamp,
    d1.quarter_name,
    d1.year
  FROM
    [datamart.order_item_lifecycle] AS order1
  INNER JOIN EACH [datamart.date_dim] AS d
  ON
    (d.month) = STRING(MONTH((order.order_timestamp))) ) AS order2
INNER JOIN EACH [datamart.date_dim] AS d2
ON
  d2.year = INTEGER(YEAR(order2.order_timestamp))
WHERE
  order2.year = STRING(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()))
GROUP BY
  order2.year,
  order2.quarter_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that you are mixing Standard SQL with Legacy SQL
Setting SQL Mode to Standard does not magically translate Legacy SQL to Standard SQL. For example - INNER JOIN EACH, [dataset.table]  notion, YEAR(), INTEGER() etc. are all from Legacy SQL and not supported in Standard SQL

So, you actually need to translate your code into Standard SQL - see [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) for more details